# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when migrating and seeding data in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

We are trying to migrate data into a sqlite3 database in Ruby with class associations between 3 classes;

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    has_many :venues, :through => :events
end
```

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :venue 
    belongs_to :artist
end
```

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    has_many :artists, :through => :events
end
```

with our seed data looking like this;

```
Event.create(id: 2599084, venue_id: 82166, playdate: "2015-06-06", name: "U2 at Pepsi Center", artist_id: "5039")
Venue.create(id: 81533, name: "Paradise Theatre", cityid: "2055", state: "CO", city: "Paonia", zip: "80246")
Artist.create(id: 5039, artistname: "U2", genre: "Pop / Rock")
```

and each migration file looking like this;

```
class CreateEventsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      #table and column to reference (join)
      t.string :name
      t.date :playdate
      t.references :artist, foreign_key: true
      t.references :venue, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateVenuesTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :venues do |t|
      #table and column to reference (join)
      t.string :name
      t.date :playdate
      t.integer :cityid
      t.string :state
      t.string :city
      t.string :zip
      t.references :artist, foreign_key: true
      t.references :event, foreign_key: true
      binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateArtistsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :artists do |t|
      #table and column to reference (join)
      t.string :artistname
      t.string :genre
    end
  end
end
```

with the intent to have every

-event reference an artist and a venue

-venue reference many events and artists

-artist referencing many events

and our results are this;

```
$ rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:49:in `to_a'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in exec_query'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:40:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:718:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:717:in `block in log'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:708:in `log'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:39:in `exec_query'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:135:in `exec_insert'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:166:in `insert'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:22:in `insert'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:375:in `_insert_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:933:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:163:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:70:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:211:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:332:in `block in _create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:332:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:111:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:906:in `create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:328:in `block in create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:328:in `create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:129:in `create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:470:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:47:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:315:in `block in save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:375:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:281:in `block in transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:280:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:278:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:281:in `transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:366:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:315:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:38:in `create'
db/seeds.rb:3235:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `block in load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.14/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake/activerecord_6.rb:3:in `load_seed'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:440:in `load_seed'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:328:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `step'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:108:in `block in each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `loop'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:107:in `each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:49:in `to_a'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in exec_query'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:40:in `block in exec_query'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:718:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:717:in `block in log'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:708:in `log'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3/database_statements.rb:39:in `exec_query'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:135:in `exec_insert'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:166:in `insert'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:22:in `insert'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:375:in `_insert_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:933:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:163:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:70:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:211:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:332:in `block in _create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_create_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:332:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:111:in `_create_record'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:906:in `create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:328:in `block in create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:827:in `_run_save_callbacks'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:328:in `create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:129:in `create_or_update'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:470:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:47:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:315:in `block in save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:375:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:281:in `block in transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:280:in `block in within_new_transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:278:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:281:in `transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:366:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:315:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:38:in `create'
db/seeds.rb:3235:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `block in load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/sinatra-activerecord-2.0.14/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake/activerecord_6.rb:3:in `load_seed'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:440:in `load_seed'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:328:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/flatironschool/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

We've googled the hell out of this, but can't seem to figure out what's wrong. We are not using Rails.

Comment: Don't use foreign key **constraints**. Use foreign keys, but without constraints, make your application to handle data consistency.

Comment: Your seeds file should create the artist before the event that references it.

Comment: As @dinjas suggested. If in your seeds you did `artist = Artist.create(...)` and then `venue = Venue.create(...)` `artist.events.create(..., venue: venue)` It should do the trick

Comment: Also, what order are your migrations in? If you try to migrate in the order you have them listing now, it will throw an error because the Venue migration is trying to create a reference to the Artist table, which hasn't been created yet.